# Calendar and CalendarRules for Equipment in Dynamics CRM 2013 SP1 through c#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on a more dynamic way of setting Work Hours for multiple resources than possible in out-of-the-box Dynamics CRM functionality.

Unfortunately I am having problems getting my code to work. I used some examples to get myself going which can be found here:
[Example 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2008/02/15/service-scheduling-exposed-partially/)
[Example 2](http://www.inogic.com/blog/2015/11/creating-calendar-rules-with-breaks-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2015/)

```
 tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Resource Reference");
                var resourceReference = resource.Contains("dp_resource") ? (EntityReference)resource.Attributes["dp_resource"] : null;
                if (resourceReference == null)
                    continue;

                tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Equipment");
                var equipment = service.Retrieve("equipment", (Guid)resourceReference.Id, new ColumnSet(new String[] { "f1_user", "calendarid" }));

                tracingService.Trace("Retrieving User Reference");
                var userReference = equipment.Contains("f1_user") ? (EntityReference)equipment.Attributes["f1_user"] : null;

                tracingService.Trace("Retrieving User");
                var user = service.Retrieve("systemuser", userReference.Id, new ColumnSet(new String[] { "calendarid", "businessunitid" }));

                tracingService.Trace("Retrieving TimeZoneCode");
                var timezone = HelperFunctions.UserSettings.RetrieveTimeZoneCodeByUserId(service, user.Id, new ColumnSet("timezonecode", "localeid"));
                tracingService.Trace("timezone -" + timezone.Value.ToString());

                tracingService.Trace("Creating Empty Calendar");
                var calendar = this.CreateEmptyCalendar(service, user);

                // Create rule to depict 8 am – 5pm  schedule  
                // This is a “root” rule and we want it to be the base on which we build  
                // User’s timezone and description of the rule  
                // Provide a user readable description  
                // One full day (1440 minutes)  
                // “Since the first day CRM is aware of”  

                tracingService.Trace("Creating Calendar Rule");
                var workHourRule = new Entity("calendarrule");
                workHourRule.Attributes.Add("extentcode", 1);
                workHourRule.Attributes.Add("rank", 0);
                workHourRule.Attributes.Add("timezonecode", (int)timezone);
                workHourRule.Attributes.Add("description", "Level 0 – Root Rule");
                workHourRule.Attributes.Add("duration", 510);
                workHourRule.Attributes.Add("pattern", "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5");
                workHourRule.Attributes.Add("starttime", new DateTime(2016, 12, 8, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
                workHourRule.Attributes.Add("innercalendarid", calendar.ToEntityReference());

                tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Calendar for Equipment");
                var equipmentCalendar = HelperFunctions.Calendar.RetrieveCalendar(service, ((EntityReference)equipment["calendarid"]).Id, new ColumnSet(true));

                tracingService.Trace("Retrieving Calendar Rules from Equipment");
                var calendarRules = equipmentCalendar.Contains("calendarrules") ? (EntityCollection)equipmentCalendar["calendarrules"] : new EntityCollection();

                //tracingService.Trace("Remove old CalendarRules");
                //calendarRules.Entities.Clear();

                tracingService.Trace("Add Calendar Rule to Calendar");
                calendarRules.Entities.Add(workHourRule);

                tracingService.Trace("Set CalendarRules attribute on Equipment Calendar");
                if (equipmentCalendar.Contains("calendarrules"))
                    equipmentCalendar["calendarrules"] = calendarRules;
                else
                    equipmentCalendar.Attributes.Add("calendarrules", calendarRules);

                tracingService.Trace("Update Equipment Calendar");
                service.Update(equipmentCalendar);
```

I am getting the following message back in the workflow:

```
Plugin Trace:

[somenamespace.FieldOne: somenamespace.FieldOne.CreateWorkHours]
[somenamespace.FieldOne (1.0.0.3): somenamespace.FieldOne.CreateWorkHours]
Start CreateWorkHours Workflow execution
Retrieving Work Hour Generation
Retrieving StartDate and EndDate of Work Hour Generation
Validating
Retrieving Work Hour Resources
Retrieving Work Hour Items
Retrieving Work Hour Resource
Retrieving Resource Reference
Retrieving Equipment
Retrieving User Reference
Retrieving User
Retrieving TimeZoneCode
timezone -110
Creating Empty Calendar
Creating Calendar Rule
Retrieving Calendar for Equipment
Retrieving Calendar Rules from Equipment
Remove old CalendarRules
Add Calendar Rule to Calendar
Set CalendarRules attribute on Equipment Calendar
Update Equipment Calendar


Error Message:

Unhandled Exception: System.Activities.InvalidWorkflowException: This operation isn’t supported
   at somenamespace.FieldOne.CreateWorkHours.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same issue 3 days back and I have found that I was creating inner calendar and setting this calendar into main calendar rule.

By default calendar type is set to 0 when we create calendar. Calendar type should be set to -1 for inner calendar, once I set this value in inner calendar my issue was resolved.

Comment: We did the same in our case and it resolved the issue. It is really a bulky structure to work with. Thank you